# How to take all images from website

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to programmatically download image from website ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636113/how-to-programmatically-download-image-from-website)
>   [Download all images from a single directory of a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622006/download-all-images-from-a-single-directory-of-a-website)

I like to take all images from given Url and also from sub URL like wwebpage crawling.

Comment: it's not exactly a dupe, but yes, there are resources there that would answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this [WebReaper](http://www.webreaper.net/). There could be many alternatives to this software. I just showed here one.